# How to get index of a substring padded with a special character

Tags: python

I am looking for a oneliner to get the index of the first and last non-hyphen character in a string. In the following example, the index of `a` and `d`. I would strip any leading or trailing hyphen `-`.

I have to do this operation some billion times.

```
---abc--d--
ans: 3, 8

---abc----
ans: 3,5
```

Based on the responses that I got from some of the best coder out there, I tried to look for the most efficient code. The running time is as follows:

```
In [48]: s = 'a-b-c-d'

In [49]: %timeit next(re.finditer('[^-].*[^-]', s)).span()
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.05 us per loop

In [50]: %timeit re.search(r'(?<=-)[^-].*[^-](?=-*$)', s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.96 us per loop

In [51]: %timeit get_first_and_last(s, '-')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 us per loop

In [52]: %timeit get_indices('---abc--d--', '-')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.53 us per loop

In [53]: %timeit get_indices(s, '-')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.09 us per loop

In [54]:
```

and the last one with best runtime:

```
In [77]: %timeit my_get_first_and_last(s,'-')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 739 ns per loop
```

Comment: some more details? why "a" and "d"? you want the first and the last char in the string?

Comment: Can you post your attempts at solving this problem? (In passing, shouldn't the second answer be `3, -1`?)

Comment: @riskio, thats right, I edited the original post.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, The string also include the hyphen

Comment: You left out the fastest one in your comparison.   `my_get_first_and_last(s, '-')` should be about `0.88 us per loop` on your machine.

Comment: @dansalmo, sorry I missed that. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> s = '---abd-d--'
>>> mid = s.strip('-')
>>> si = s.index(mid[0])
>>> si, si + len(mid) - 1
(3, 7)
```

To compare to Inbar Rose's best solution:

```
def my_get_first_and_last(s, filler):
    mid = s.strip('-')
    si = s.index(mid[0])
    return si, si + len(mid) - 1

def get_first_and_last(s, filler):
    trimmed = s.strip(filler)
    return s.index(trimmed[0]), len(s) - 1 - s[::-1].index(trimmed[-1])

>>> timeit.Timer("my_get_first_and_last('---abc--d--', '-')", "from __main__ import get_first_and_last").repeat()
[1.5137124020474033, 1.5367783393705707, 1.5110408799341997]
>>> timeit.Timer("get_first_and_last('---abc--d--', '-')", "from __main__ import get_first_and_last").repeat()
[2.3410303195946653, 2.317741755428642, 2.304720330642567]
>>> timeit.Timer("get_indices('---abc--d--', '-')", "from __main__ import get_indices").repeat()
[3.2813887808902678, 3.201712109488767, 3.150435437574032]
```

Comment: what do you think about `---abd-d--`?

Answer (score 2):

One option:

```
def get_indices(s, filler):
    parts = filter(None, s.split(filler))
    return s.index(parts[0]), s.index(parts[-1])+len(parts[-1])-1

>>> get_indices('---abc--d--', '-')
(3, 8)
>>> get_indices('---abc----', '-')
(3, 5)
```

The logic is to get all the parts that are not the filler. Then to take the first part and find its index - that's the first non filler item. Then you take the last part and find its index + the length of the last part (minus 1 because the index already takes a spot) - now you have the last non filler item.

---

Another option:

```
def get_first_and_last(s, filler):
    trimmed = s.strip(filler)
    return s.index(trimmed[0]), len(s) - 1 - s[::-1].index(trimmed[-1])

>>> get_first_and_last('---abc--d--', '-')
(3, 8)
>>> get_first_and_last('---abc----', '-')
(3, 5)
```

The logic is to clean the filler from both sides. Then find the index of the start of the trimmed string in the original string for the first index. And then find the index of the last item in the trimmed string, in order to make sure it works properly, we reverse the original string, and then subtract it from the length - 1 of the original string.

---

Timing the better option:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer("get_first_and_last('---abc--d--', '-')", "from __main__ import get_first_and_last").repeat()
[1.260409049800318, 1.2315312125653757, 1.2293705754911328]
>>> timeit.Timer("get_indices('---abc--d--', '-')", "from __main__ import get_indices").repeat()
[1.7771399534411891, 1.7077849342434739, 1.698285322233577]
```

Looks like `get_first_and_last` is a better choice here.

Answer (score 1):

Some inefficient way to get the indices:

```
ss = ["---abc--d--", "---abc----" ]
for s in ss: 
    stripped = s.strip("-")
    idx = s.index(stripped) 
    print idx, idx + len(stripped) - 1
```

*Gives:*

```
3 8
3 5
```

But the regex version should be faster:

```
import re
ss = ["---abc--d--", "---abc----" ]
re_m = re.compile(r'(?<=-)[^-].*[^-](?=-*$)')
for s in ss: 
    m = re.search(re_m, s)
    print m.start(), m.end() - 1
```

Comment: @user1140126, yep, the regex is slow, but the first one is 2 times faster than the accepted answer

Comment: @user1140126, True,  I converged on the same solution, but it looks like perreal had it first but called it slow.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a `re.finditer`, and find from the first a to the last d:

```
import re
print next(re.finditer('a.*d', s)).span()
# (3, 9)
```

Or more general... (for first not hyphen, until the last not hypen):

```
start, end = next(re.finditer('[^-].*[^-]', s)).span()
```

Note that the span will be a half-open range suitable for usage such as slicing the substring from your original string (`s[start:end]` for instance). If indeed you want the last characters' index, then you will need to take 1 from the `end`.

Comment: IIUC `a` and `d` are only examples, so wouldn't we need a non-hyphen character class?

Comment: @DSM haha... strange you should mention that - guess what I had open in an editor :)

Comment: Heh.  Might be worth mentioning that `span` is half-open, as opposed to the OP's closed.  [Congrats on almost hitting 40k, btw!  Probably later today, I expect.]

Comment: @DSM I did have "and just the returned span" - ... which is a bit of a typo... but I could be more explicit... and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a one liner, but doesn't require you create a new strings or lists in memory (which may be valuable if you're executing this billions of times).

```
def find_indices(data, ignore="-"):
    start = 0
    end = len(data)-1
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i] != ignore:
            start = i
            break
    for i in range(len(data)-1, 0, -1):
        if data[i] != ignore:
            end = i
            break
    return (start, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

oneliner solution:

```
import re
s = '---abc--d--'
[s.index(re.findall("[^-]",s)[i]) for i in [0,-1]]
```